# Loading data from Firebase real time database to React hook component

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hook-form

I'm new to Firebase's real-time database and I have found out that some React hook codes are different than Firestore. With that being said, I tried to make a functional component to drop onto the main app. I'm trying to match the value in code but I haven't figured it out.

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Button,
  CardTitle,

} from "reactstrap";

const Configs = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState("");
  
    const getUser = () => {
      const cdb = firebase.database().ref("/pos").child("/pos1")
      let userlist = [];
      cdb.on("value", (snapshot) => {
          userlist.forEach(snapshot=> {
            userlist.push(snapshot.val());
          });
          console.log(JSON.stringify(snapshot, null, 2));
          setUserData(userlist);
      }
      )
    
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      getUser();
    }, []);
  
    const handleUpdate = () => {
      firebase.database()
      .ref("/pos")
      .child("/post1")
      .update({
        pos1_a: userData.pos1_a,
        pos1_b: userData.pos1_b,
        pos1_c: userData.pos1_c,
      })
      .then(()=> {
        console.log('Pos Updated')
      })
    };
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="page-content">
            <Row>
              <Col>

                    <CardTitle className="h4">Main Configurations</CardTitle>
                    <p className="card-title-desc">
                      Settings will be written on<code> database</code> applied to
                      the webhook loads <code>&lt;input&gt;</code> <code>type</code>
                      .
                    </p>
    
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="example-text-input"
                        className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                      >
                        userData_A
                      </label>
                      <div className="col-md-10">
                        <div>
                          <input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="number"
                            min="0"
                            value={userData ? userData.pos1_a : ""}
                            onChange={(txt) =>
                              setUserData({
                                ...userData,
                                pos1_a: txt,
                              })
                            }
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="example-search-input"
                        className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                      >
                        userData_B
                      </label>
                      <div className="col-md-10">
                        <div>
                          <input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="number"
                            min="0"
                            value={userData ? userData.pos1_b : ""}
                            onChange={(txt) =>
                              setUserData({
                                ...userData,
                                pos1_b: txt,
                              })
                            }
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </Row>
                    <Row className="mb-3">
                      <label
                        htmlFor="example-search-input"
                        className="col-md-2 col-form-label"
                      >
                        userData_C
                      </label>
                      <div className="col-md-10">
                        <div>
                          <input
                            className="form-control"
                            type="number"
                            min="0"
                            value={userData ? userData.pos1_b : ""}
                            onChange={(txt) =>
                              setUserData({
                                ...userData,
                                pos1_b: txt,
                              })
                            }
                          />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </Row>
                    
                    <Button
                    buttonTitle="Update"
                    color="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    onPress={handleUpdate}
                  >
                    Submit change
                  </Button>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default Configs;

    ```
````

The console.log has got the data in JSON so I think it is in object form.
The point of the exercise for me is to get the form updates to sync with real-time db. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the structure of your database but basicaly you have 2 possible solutions:

1. You data is saved as a list:

```js
const tempList = [];

userlist.forEach((snapshot) => {
  tempList.push(snapshot.val());
});

setUserData(tempList);
```

You where using here the same variable `userlist`

2. Your data is an Object:

```
const tempList = [];

userlist.forEach((snapshot) => {
  Object.entries(snapshot.val()).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    tempList.push(value);
  });
});

setUserData(tempList);
```

Comment: My bad. The JSON is very simple
{
  "post1": { 
    "pos1_a" : "1",
    "pos1_b" : "abc",
    "pos1_c" : "test"
  }
}
I am trying to map the data onto an object and save them all together.

Comment: Then the second code should work for you.